# Flutter: Invalid internet address firebasestorage.googleapis.com

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, exception, firebase-storage

When I link to a picture from firebase, it throws an error for every picture in the file: **socket_patch.dart:238**

```
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Invalid internet address firebasestorage.googleapis.com)
```

[image: Exception image]

Before it's works.

Comment: It seems the _parse function returns null, thus the exception. Why it returns null - it depends on what this function does and how it does it.

Comment: Check out these bugs: [bug1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82405), [bug2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83792).

Comment: did you solve this error if yes how?

Comment: As previously mentioned by @jabbson, `inAddr` gets null from `_parse(address)`. Please provide more details on how address is handled inside _parse() - which causes for an error to be thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Flutter bug and It's fixed in version "2.5.3". just use the "Flutter upgrade" command in terminal